# Avalon Dock Anchorable Control is not working if AllowTransparency Set to True

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I am using LayoutAnchorable of Avalon Dock to dock my toolbar in my WPF application. Everything works fine. But as soon as I set the AllowTransparency property of parent window to true, it stopped working.

AnchorableControl is being shown as it should. When I unpin it, it docks itself to side of the window. But it nevers comes up upon hovering the mouse over it.

I am trying to find a workaround in the source control of Avalon dock. but there is lot to take and code isn't very straight.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly many `Controls` (including HWND etc.) are not working when `AllowTransparency` is set to true. But this is outdated anyway.

If you want to style your `Window` take a look at the [WindowChrome](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx) Class and/or use a the very good Design Library [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/)

Edit:
Found the reason [here](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/workitem/15270).

Comment: I am already using Mahapps in my application. I am using Avalon for docking purposes

Comment: Why do you need `AllowTransparency` then?

Comment: Application needs a feature to make it 50% transparent on some of the occasions. To make it 50% transparent I need to set the allow transparency to true.

Comment: There is only one way but you will need to modify Avalon source code. Find static constructor of LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindowControl class and override contentproperty metadata with ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindowControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, null));